# Create a unique string for users that can tell you who's string it is

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have some data that is being given to users in the form of a string. However, I do not want these strings to be able to be shared across users, which means that they should not be able to reverse/modify the string to work for themselves. Also, I want to be able to protect users who share their strings for their own safety. Also, I need to be able to extract the plaintext/original string.

Is this possible to do in Node.js?

My current idea is this:

Take the plain string, encrypt it using the MD5 hash of the given user's username. Append the hash to this encrypted string, encrypt all of this with the username.

However, I don't like this method because it uses a system which, once reversed, can be used  to crack all strings for all users.

Comment: Don't use MD5, it is broken.  Use SHA256 or SHA3 instead.  You also need to add [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) and [stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) for security.

Comment: @rossum hello, the hashing algorithm I use is besides the point. I still need a way to encrypt this string, only access it as the person it is intended for, and know who's string it is if it is not.

Comment: You have three problems here.  1. Password security for each user.  2. Encryption of the user's data and 3. Identifying string ownership.  You would do better to separate the problems.  1 and 2 have standard solutions, I outlined solution 1 before.  For problem 3, merely append  some user ID to the string, or have an associated field in your database identifying the owner.